# SSL Configuration Unable to read server.crt file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to go through this tutorial here

Creating a Self Signed SSL Certificate

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-certificate-self

I generated the csr, and the key and generated the certificate csr

When I head back to the ssl heroku tutorial

I tried

heroku certs:add server.crt bundle.pem server.key

but its giving me this error

```
Resolving trust chain... failed
 !    Unable to read server.crt file
```

I am pretty sure I have server.crt, because when I generated it, the contents popped up. I didn't get an error.

I am quite new to heroku, I managed to deploy a small rails app to heroku last night

I am not using nginx or pow from this railscasts video which I haven't watched yet

http://railscasts.com/episodes/357-adding-ssl

could this be a problem?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem when I specified application name with incorrect command line switch (-app ). As soon as I used correct switch --app (two dashes) the error disappeared. So this must be a generic error, misleading of course, that the SSL addon prints.