# Heroku SSL Configuration Unable to read server.crt file

Tags: ssl, heroku, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm having the same issue as Jngai1297 here: [SSL Configuration Unable to read server.crt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590752/ssl-configuration-unable-to-read-server-crt-file), only I think I've spelled everything correctly.

I am trying to update our ssl certificate. We purchased a cert from startssl.com. I downloaded the ssl.key file, and retrieved my ssl.crt file, I also downloaded sub.class2.server.ca.pem and ca.pem

I ran:

```
openssl rsa -in ssl.key -out sslnopas.key
cat ssl.crt sub.class2.server.ca.pem ca.pem > concatenated.crt 
heroku certs:update concatenated.crt sslnopass.key --app <MYAPPNAME>
```

with  as my actual application name, but I'm getting:

```
Resolving trust chain... failed
!    Unable to read concatenated.crt file
```

Is there any way I could get a better error message? I'm on the latest version of heroku toolbelt 3.6.0

Comment: Update, I tried excluding the ca.pem when I made my concatenated.crt - as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22400372/heroku-ssl-issue-its-give-me-verification-fails but get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - I misspelled the sslnopass.key file! The concatenated.crt file was fine, and the error message was wrong. Looks like this is Heroku's default error message for just about anything that goes wrong with this call.